# How to launch a wpf app from vba for outlook and call a procedure from this app

Tags: vba, wpf, vb.net, shell, outlook

I have created a wpf app using vb.net 4.0 and installed this app on my PC. This app has a GUI with a button that launch a procedure. My app is pretty complex and going back to vba is out of the table.

What i want to do is launch the app and trigger this procedure automatically from outlook when a specific new email comes in (once a day). I figured how to use the `Shell` method in vba for outlook to start my app.

But now my question is: is there any way to simulate the click on the GUI button (from vba in outlook, using a script or any other method...)?

Or does the app knows where it has been started from so that i can launch the procedure at startup if the execution was called from outlook via `Shell`?

I would like to avoid to have to publish a new app where the procedure is called at startup, so that I only have 1 source code and so that I can continue to use my app manually.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then you want to launch a .NET WPF application from Outlook VBA and have it run some startup procedure.

If this is the case then I recommend passing some extra command line parameter when you use `VBA.Shell`.  The WPF app can read its own command line parameters, here is a tutorial.

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/command-line-parameters/

If you need to influence the WPF app's behaviour later then that would be less simple, please comment if you need that.

Comment: Yes. I want to run the procedure at startup only if the app was started using vba in outlook (via the shell). Else (if the program was started from the taskbar, the main menu,...)  the program starts normaly and then the user click on a button to start the procedure. I'll try your solution.

Comment: I tested it and it works great. Before your comment I started investigating windows api to click on the button programmatically, but your solution is much cleaner. Thank you.